# Character encoding in TTL file

Tags: character-encoding, ontology, protege, turtle-rdf

I have the following TTL file (exported from WebProtege) which includes food ingredients like the following:

```
:water rdf:type :FoodIngredient ;
       skos:prefLabel "Water" ;
       skos:altLabel "Acqua"@it ,
                     "Agua"@es ,
                     "Eau"@fr ,
                     "Wasser"@de ,
                     "Ã¡gua"@pt ,
                     "Î�Î•Î¡ÎŸ"@el ,
                     "ã‚¢ã‚¤ã‚¹ã‚­ãƒ¥ãƒ¼ãƒ–"@ja ,
                     "æ°´"@ja ,
                     "æ°·"@ja .
```

I guess the character encoding of the file does not permit the correct rendering of the last 2 labels, so is there a way to retrieve the correct labels?

**EDIT**: After following [teapot418](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21105992/teapot418)'s suggestion (see comments section), I did `iconv -c -f utf8 -t latin1` and I now have the following output:

```
:water rdf:type :FoodIngredient ;
       skos:prefLabel "Water" ;
       skos:altLabel "Acqua"@it ,
                     "Agua"@es ,
                     "Eau"@fr ,
                     "Wasser"@de ,
                     "Ã¡gua"@pt ,
                     "Î�Î•Î¡ÎŸ"@el ,
                     "ã‚¢ã‚¤ã‚¹ã‚­ãƒ¥ãƒ¼ãƒ–"@ja ,
                     "水"@ja ,
                     "氷"@ja .
```

Any help on resolving the encoding issue with the two erroneous labels would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The Japanese bit looks like [utf8/Western mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake#Japanese). Either you need to adjust your viewer to display utf8 or if the file is messed up, you can try [reversing the encoding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122588/recovering-mojibaked-files).

Comment: A-ha, thanks a lot @teapot418, this worked partially, here is what I have now:

`:water rdf:type :FoodIngredient ;
       skos:prefLabel "Water" ;
       skos:altLabel "Acqua"@it ,
                     "Agua"@es ,
                     "Eau"@fr ,
                     "Wasser"@de ,
                     "Ã¡gua"@pt ,
                     "��Ρ�"@el ,
                     "�������"@ja ,
                     "水"@ja ,
                      "氷"@ja .`
The two last labels were indeed "salvaged".

Comment: Doesn't that prove the problem is in your viewer, not Protégé? Can you add the actual file content as it shows when seen in UTF8, or add the  expected values in a format that allows for replication? (Most formats expect utf-8 and will emit utf-8 by default.)

Comment: @Ignazio I load the file in IntelliJ Idea and it is by default in UTF-8. Doesn't this indicate that the file is messed up in the first place?

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case originated from (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): ```print('"água"@pt, "ΝΕΡΟ"@el, "アイスキューブ"@ja, "水"@ja, "氷"@ja'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252', 'replace'))``` returns ```"Ã¡gua"@pt, "Î�Î•Î¡ÎŸ"@el, "ã‚¢ã‚¤ã‚¹ã‚­ãƒ¥ãƒ¼ãƒ–"@ja, "æ°´"@ja, "æ°·"@ja```. Not reversible (as is) due to the  `�` (U+FFFD,  *Replacement Character*) in Greek string (because `\x9d` is unprintable in `cp1252`).